# Majority Voting in perl?

Tags: perl

I have 5 files containing the same words. I want to read each word in all the files and decide the winning word by detecting the following characters in a word (*, #, $, &) separated by tabs. Then, I want to generate an output file. Ii can only have 2 winners. For example:

file1

```
    we$
    are*
    ...
```

file2

```
    we$
    are#
    ...
```

file3

```
    we&
    are*
    ...
```

file4

```
    we$
    are#
    ...
```

file5

```
    we$
    are&
    ...
```

output file:

```
we$                       
are*#
```

Here is how I started:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

sub read_file_line {
  my $fh = shift;    
  if ($fh and my $line = <$fh>) {    
    chomp($line);    
    return $line;
  }    
  return;    
}

open(my $f1, "words1.txt") or die "Can't";
open(my $f2, "words2.txt") or die "Can't";
open(my $f3, "words3.txt") or die "Can't";
open(my $f4, "words4.txt") or die "Can't";
open(my $f5, "words5.txt") or die "Can't";

my $r1 = read_file_line($f1);
my $r2 = read_file_line($f2);
my $r3 = read_file_line($f3);
my $r4 = read_file_line($f4);
my $r5 = read_file_line($f5);

while ($f5) {

    #What can I do here to decide and write the winning word in the output file?

$r1 = read_file_line($f1);
$r2 = read_file_line($f2);
$r3 = read_file_line($f3);
$r4 = read_file_line($f4);
$r5 = read_file_line($f5);
}
```

Comment: The smell, you know that [alcohol](http://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/Shower_Board_as_a_white_Board#CAS_numbers) smell. The whole board. Smells like... homework.

Comment: Hey - the revised question is a trivial variant on the previous one; you should be able to adapt any of the previous solutions to the new scenario.  And changing the question so that the previous answers are all irrelevant is non-kosher.  So, too, is not marking the question as homework when it is clearly homework.  Then not thinking about your revised requirement is pure laziness on your part.

Comment: I'm really sorry, i changed the question to make you understand what the second approach is not to make it irrelevant. its a project that i got stack into try to seek for your help. im sorry.

Comment: @aliocee: OK - you've learned.  Please remember for the future.  Thanks!

Comment: @aliocee: [homework on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Test Data Generator

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $i (1..5)
{
    my $file = "words$i.txt";
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Failed to open $file for writing ($!)";
    foreach my $w (qw (we are the people in charge and what we say goes))
    {
        my $suffix = substr('*#$&', rand(4), 1);
        print $fh "$w$suffix\n";
    }
}
```

#### Majority Voting Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = ( "words1.txt", "words2.txt", "words3.txt",
              "words4.txt", "words5.txt"
            );

my @fh;
{
    my $n = 0;
    foreach my $file (@files)
    {
        open my $f, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file for reading ($!)";
        $fh[$n++] = $f;
    }
}

while (my $r = process_line(@fh))
{
    print "$r\n";
}

sub process_line
{
    my(@fhlist) = @_;
    my %words = ();
    foreach my $fh (@fhlist)
    {
        my $line = <$fh>;
        return unless defined $line;
        chomp $line;
        $words{$line}++;
    }

    my $combo = '';
    foreach my $word (keys %words)
    {
        return $word    if ($words{$word} >  2);
        $combo .= $word if ($words{$word} == 2);
    }
    $combo =~ s/(\W)\w+(\W)/$1$2/;
    return $combo;
}
```

#### Example Data and Results

```
$ perl datagenerator.pl
$ perl majorityvoter.pl > results.txt
$ paste words?.txt results.txt
we*     we$     we&     we#     we#     we#
are*    are#    are#    are*    are$    are*#
the*    the&    the#    the#    the&    the&#
people& people& people$ people# people# people&#
in#     in*     in$     in*     in*     in*
charge* charge# charge& charge* charge# charge#*
and$    and*    and$    and&    and$    and$
what&   what&   what$   what&   what#   what&
we#     we*     we*     we&     we*     we*
say$    say&    say$    say$    say$    say$
goes$   goes&   goes#   goes#   goes#   goes#
$
```

This seems to be correct for the test data in the files generated.

---

#### Revised requirements - example output

The 'revised requirements' replaced the '*#$&' markers after the words with a tab and one of the letters 'ABCD'.  After some swift negotiation, the question is restored to its original form.  This output is from a suitably adapted version of the answer above - 3 code lines changed, 2 in the data generator, 1 in the majority voter.  Those changes are not shown - they are trivial.

```
we      C       we      D       we      C       we      C       we      D       we      C
are     C       are     D       are     C       are     B       are     A       are     C
the     B       the     D       the     A       the     A       the     D       the     A|D
people  D       people  B       people  A       people  B       people  D       people  B|D
in      D       in      B       in      C       in      B       in      D       in      D|B
charge  C       charge  D       charge  D       charge  D       charge  A       charge  D
and     A       and     B       and     C       and     C       and     B       and     B|C
what    B       what    B       what    B       what    C       what    C       what    B
we      D       we      B       we      D       we      B       we      A       we      B|D
say     D       say     D       say     B       say     D       say     D       say     D
goes    A       goes    C       goes    A       goes    C       goes    A       goes    A
```

#### Revised test generator - for configurable number of files

Now that the poster has worked out how to handle the revised scenario, this is the data generator code I used - with 5 tags (A-E).  Clearly, it would not take a huge amount of work to configure the number of tags on the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fmax  = scalar(@ARGV) > 0 ? $ARGV[0] : 5;
my $tags  = 'ABCDE';
my $ntags = length($tags);
my $fmt   = sprintf "words$fmax-%%0%0dd.txt", length($fmax);

foreach my $fnum (1..$fmax)
{
    my $file = sprintf $fmt, $fnum;
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Failed to open $file for writing ($!)";
    foreach my $w (qw(We Are The People In Charge And What We Say Goes))
    {
        my $suffix = substr($tags, rand($ntags), 1);
        print $fh "$w\t$suffix\n";
    }
}
```

#### Revised Majority Voting Code - for arbitrary number of files

This code works with basically arbitrary numbers of files.  As noted in one of the (many) comments, it does not check that the word is the same in each file as required by the question; you could get quirky results if the words are not the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = scalar @ARGV > 0 ? @ARGV :
            ( "words1.txt", "words2.txt", "words3.txt",
              "words4.txt", "words5.txt"
            );
my $voters = scalar(@files);

my @fh;
{
    my $n = 0;
    foreach my $file (@files)
    {
        open my $f, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file for reading ($!)";
        $fh[$n++] = $f;
    }
}

while (my $r = process_line(@fh))
{
    print "$r\n";
}

sub process_line
{
    my(@fhlist) = @_;
    my %words = ();
    foreach my $fh (@fhlist)
    {
        my $line = <$fh>;
        return unless defined $line;
        chomp $line;
        $words{$line}++;
    }
    return winner(%words);
}

# Get tag X from entry "word\tX".
sub get_tag_from_word
{
    my($word) = @_;
    return (split /\s/, $word)[1];
}

sub winner
{
    my(%words)   = @_;
    my $maxscore = 0;
    my $winscore = ($voters / 2) + 1;
    my $winner   = '';
    my $taglist  = '';
    foreach my $word (sort keys %words)
    {
        return "$word\t$words{$word}" if ($words{$word} >= $winscore);
        if ($words{$word} > $maxscore)
        {
            $winner = $word;
            $winner =~ s/\t.//;
            $taglist = get_tag_from_word($word);
            $maxscore = $words{$word};
        }
        elsif ($words{$word} == $maxscore)
        {
            my $newtag = get_tag_from_word($word);
            $taglist .= "|$newtag";
        }
    }
    return "$winner\t$taglist\t$maxscore";
}
```

#### One Example Run

After considerable experimentation on the data presentation, one particular set of data I generated gave the result:

```
We          A|B|C|D|E   2  B  C  C  E  D  A  D  A  E  B
Are         D           4  C  D  B  A  D  B  D  D  B  E
The         A           5  D  A  B  B  A  A  B  E  A  A
People      D           4  E  D  C  D  B  E  D  D  B  C
In          D           3  E  C  D  D  D  B  C  A  A  B
Charge      A|E         3  E  E  D  A  D  A  B  A  E  B
And         E           3  C  E  D  D  C  A  B  E  B  E
What        A           5  B  C  C  A  A  A  B  A  D  A
We          A           4  C  A  A  E  A  E  C  D  A  E
Say         A|D         4  A  C  A  A  D  E  D  A  D  D
Goes        A           3  D  B  A  C  C  A  A  E  E  B
```

The first column is the word; the second is the winning tag or tags; the third (numeric) column is the maximum score; the remaining 10 columns are the tags from the 10 data files.  As you can see, there two each of 'We A', 'We B', ... 'We E' in the first row.  I've also generated (but not preserved) one result set where the maximum score was 7.  Given enough repetition, these sorts of variations are findable.

Comment: I try editing your codes to implement the edited version of my question using (A,B,C,D instead of *,#,$,&) separated by tab character but i cant detect the majority word in the regular expression. any suggestion please? thanks.

Comment: @aliocee: THINK!  There are two lines to change in datagenerator.pl and one line to change in majorityvoter.pl - it is that trivial a change in requirements.  This is a site for LEARNING; that means you are expected to learn from the answers given you.

Comment: @aliocee: and a Happy New Year to you, too!

Comment: yes, i put (A,B,C,D) into an array then randomise the index, i dont have any problem with the datagenerator.pl, its the majorityvoter.pl the is giving problem thats why i decided to ask you. this is what i change in the regular expression: $combo =~ s/(A|B|C|D)\w+(A|B|C|D)/$1$2/; but having problems.

Comment: @aliocee: the line that needs to be changed in the majority voter script is the substitute expression in the line reading `$combo =~ s/(\W)\w+(\W)/$1$2/;`.  You need to understand how that works in the original context; it is then trivial to adapt it to the revised requirement.  Use '[...]' character classes, and don't forget about the tabs you added.

Comment: $combo =~ s/(A|B|C|D)[\w+\t](A|B|C|D)/$1$2/; ?

Comment: @aliocee: more or less.  The combo contains a word, a tab, a letter from `[A-D]`, the word again, another tab, and another letter.  You need one of the words, a tab, and the two letters separated by a pipe.  In case of doubt, print intermediate values; that is standard debugging technique, especially for code that isn't your own that you don't fully understand (or even for code that you wrote but no longer fully understand!).

Comment: $combo =~ s/([A-D])\t\w+([A-D]\|[A-D])/$1$2/; here is what i understand from your explanation is this correct?

Comment: @aliocee: Your substitute looks for letter, tab, word, letter; where did the literal pipe and the next letter come from? Read my previous comment again, carefully. The substitute operation in the original bypassed the first word - started matching after the end of the word, at the punctuation character. So, your revised expression needs to start matching after the end of the first word, starting with a tab. Your replacement string will insert the pipe symbol; it isn't in `$combo` to be matched, as you'd see if you put a `printf "<<$combo>>\n";` statement before and after the substitute.

Comment: @aliocee: I'm not cross with you now - I probably was earlier.  I am trying to get you to think methodically, because that is the most crucial programming skill there is.  There is system in the way regexes work, and programs in general, and you need to learn how to see the system through the syntax.  That is, the syntax (especially for regexes) is obscure or ghastly (or both), but you have to see past the surface level of confusion to the method underneath.  See http://regex.info/ or http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: $combo =~ s/([A-D])\w+\t([A-D])/$1\|$2/; ?

Comment: @aliocee: Did that new version work for you?  It is marginally different from mine, but marginally neater too.  Fortunately, it's Perl and TMTOWTDI - there's more than one way to do it.  (That looks correct to me.)

Comment: for the record you are a get teacher, thanks alot for not getting angry with me sure u r a patient guy.

Comment: i verified its correct, now u know you that i can put effort to learn new things in programming. please can u tell me ur methed as well?

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ You can check the validity of your regexen there; There's a bunch of sites like that, but this one includes support for recursive patterns and a bunch of cool stuff that hopefully you'll never have to use : ) For instance, to get my previous solution working, you'd need to change the regex to /(\p{Ll}+)\s+(\p{Lu})/.. Which isn't supported in the site I just linked you to. Dammit! You should take a look at perlretut, perlre, and this: http://www.perladvent.org/2010/1/

Comment: @Jonathan - Because my method will not match the word that start with capital letter from A-D, also i may change the array in the datagenerator.pl to be like @a = qw(AW BX CY DZ); instead of @a = qw(A B C D); base on my project. in this case, [A-D] expression will not work. but may be it will work on your method.

Comment: On the contrary! If your regex doesn't match the data, you can't change the data: Change the regex! /([a-z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)/ ought to do the trick.

Comment: About the last regex you posted.

Comment: @aliocee: What I wrote was `$combo =~ s/\t([A-D])\w+\t([A-D])/\t$1|$2/;` which includes the tab character twice where yours doesn't bother.  Yours works fine; mine does too.  Nominally, mine might spot some erroneous data yours doesn't (missing tabs, specifically), but that's not really an issue here.

Comment: @aliocee: Reading through your comment about initial capitals etc, I went and capitalized the sentence in the data generator, and then ran it through my voter script, and it worked fine because I explicitly looked for the tab, [A-D], word, tab, [A-D]; the leading tab protected me from all problems.  Maybe I should partially retract my previous comment - it is a good idea to look for that leading tab explicitly.  But it was reflexive on my part; I did it automatically without really noticing the repetition until you posted your variant.

Comment: @Jonathan - thanks alot for ur help, i just tested using what i explain to you in the last comment i sent to you, it is also working fine.

Comment: @Jonathan - in mine, its not working after i capitalised some of the words, which was why i asked for your solution.

Comment: @aliocee: As @Hugmeir noted, most people cannot simply change the data format to suit their needs - the data format is given and you have to adapt to what is given.  It is good that you are able to make it work with the alternative; it shows you are thinking about the problem and a possible solution.  However, be wary of changing the starting conditions unless you are supposed to be in charge of them.  (When you are in charge of the formats, you ensure that things are as easy to parse as possible; the punctuation suffix was an excellent example of 'easy to parse'.)

Comment: i have a question, what if the number of files increase from 5 to 10?

Comment: @aliocee: The array increases from 5 to 10; the conditions for which is the majority becomes more complex.  How much more so depends on whether the number of tags increases from 4 to some larger number...

Comment: Yes tags increases from 4 to 5 as well?

Comment: @aliocee: What rules have you come up with?  (1) When is there an outright winner? (2) How are you going to deal with the case where there are three tags all with 3 entries?  (3) How are you going to deal with the case where there are five tags all with 2 entries?  (4) Are there any other extrema to worry about?  You probably need to split the 'process_line()` sub into two - one part reads the line as now; the other deals with the majority voting stuff, which is about to get tougher.  Extending the array (from 5 to 10 to any number) is easy - that's the advantage of arrays.  Voting is harder.

Comment: @Jonathan - (1) a winner will be the one with higher number all the time it 1 or more. (2) all 3 will be winners separated with pipe character (3) all 5 will be winners as well separated with pipe character. (4) For now no extra this is the final stage.

Comment: im trying to figure out since yesterday, because you told me to try on my own but cant get the answer to the voting part, i cant sleep until i finish this last part.

Comment: @aliocee: given N voters (files), what is the formula for when someone is the outright winner? (1 voter → 1 vote; 2 → 2; 3 → 2; 4 → 3; 5 → 3; ...).  If there isn't an outright winner, then (supposing you have 10 voters), you might see a score of, say 1, first, then 2, then later you might see a score of 3 (out of 10), and later again another score of 3.  Once you've seen a score of 2, all scores of 1 are uninteresting; once you've seen a score of 3, the scores of 2 are uninteresting. When scoring, you probably split the word and the tag (A-E) and store the word and the list of tags separately.

Comment: @Jonathan - please can u guide me with a short algorithm?

Comment: @aliocee: My previous comment gives you most of the algorithm.  You don't have to use the outright winner number.  You need to keep track of the current maximum number of votes.  When a new vote comes in with fewer votes, it is uninteresting and can be ignored.  When a new vote comes in with more votes, you discard the information about the previous high vote count and record the new high vote, the word, and the tag (A-E if there are 5 tags).  When the new vote has the same number of votes as the previous high vote count, you need to add its tag to the list of tags.  This gives you the winner.

Comment: sub process_line
{
    my(@fhlist) = @_;
    my %words = ();
    foreach my $fh (@fhlist)
    {
        my $line = <$fh>;
        return unless defined $line;
        chomp $line;
        $words{$line}++;
    }

    return voter(%words); 

}

sub voter
{ 
   my(%words) = @_;

   foreach my $word (keys %words)
   {
        my @tags = split(/\t/, $word);
 
 
   }
}

Comment: @aliocee: the revised process_line() looks practically identical to mine - I called the second sub winner instead of voter, but that's about all. The outline of the voter sub is a start; you have a bit more work to do in the loop body. I have a constant $winscore; any word with at least that many votes is automatically the winner. I have variables $maxscore (initially zero), $winner and $taglist. When there's a new maximum score, I set things appropriately; when there's a new score with the same score, I add its tag to $taglist; otherwise, I ignore it. At the end, format up the answer. –

Comment: One might argue that at some point, the code should check that the word portion of each line from each file matches - so that one file does not say `hello\tA` while another says `goodbye\tZ` on the same line number.  However, that is nominally out of scope; the code shown above simply assumes that the word is the same.  It actually only matters if you have (say) two lines saying `hello\tA` and two other lines saying `goodbye\tB`; then you'll get told either `hello\tA|B` or `goodbye\tA|B` is the winner.  Note that the `$maxscore` algorithm would be correct with 26 tags (A-Z) and only 10 files.

Comment: All files have the same content, only the tags (A-E) differs from each other in the 10 files. therefore i can hello\tA|B as HELLO occur in all 10 files. you can easily understand from your datagenerator.pl file.

Comment: Yes, ten files are the maximum i have.

Comment: sub voter
{ 
   my(%words) = @_;

   my $max = 0;
   my ($win,$list) = ("",""); 

   foreach my $word (keys %words)
   {
        my @tags = split(/\t/, $word); 
 
 if($words{$word} >  $max){
      $max = $words{$word};
      
             if ($list eq ""){ 
       $list .= $tags[1];
          $win = $tags[0];
      }
             else{
                $list .= "|" . $tags[1];  
              $win = $tags[0];
             } 
 }
 
   }

   return $win . "\t" . $list; 
}

Comment: Here is my last version it seems working but i have to verify it. check it for me please.

Comment: @aliocee: Getting close, but not quite right.  If `$words{$word} > $max`, then you need to set `$max`, `$list`, and `$win` unconditionally to the new values; else if `$words{$word} == $max`, then you need to add the new tag to the list of tags; else you can ignore the new entry.  I generally aim to avoid the '.' operator, so I'd write: `return "$win\t$list";`, for example, or `$list .= "|$tags[1]";`.  I think it makes for clearer reading; I'm not sure about efficiency.

Comment: sub voter
{ 
   my(%words) = @_;

   my $max = 0;
   my ($win,$list) = ("",""); 

   foreach my $word (keys %words)
   {
        my @tags = split(/\t/, $word); 
 
 if($words{$word} >  $max){

      $max  = $words{$word};               
             $win  = $tags[0];
             $list = $tags[1];
 }
        elsif ($words{$word} >  $max){ 
       
             $list .= "|$tags[1]";
 } 
        else{

 }          
 
   }

   return "$win\t$list";
}

Comment: What a great teacher you are ! i really appreciate all what you've done for me.

Comment: @aliocee: the `elsif` condition needs `==` in place of `>`, but otherwise correct.  You normally wouldn't write `else {}` but it isn't technically wrong.

Comment: Please why did you set `$winscore;` to  constant ?

Comment: @aliocee: I set `$winscore` to `($voters / 2) + 1`; if I the new score is greater than or equal to `$winscore`, then this is the winning score with no possibility of any other score equalling or exceeding it - so the loop can terminate early.  It is a minor optimization.

Comment: @Jonathan - I have a question in my question list, the question is: Matching words in a sentence using Perl? please can you give me your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @aliocee: I suggest writing it up as a complete new question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - i have written a new question as you suggested, please take a look at it. the question is "How can i duplicate sentence base on words cooccurance? in perl". thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the job for a [hash of hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES). Untested code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;
use List::Util qw( sum reduce );

my %totals;

my @files = map "words$_.txt", 1..5;

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my ($word, $sign) = /(\w+)(\W)/;
        $totals{$word}{$sign}++;
    }
}

open my $totals_fh, '>', 'outfile.txt';

my @sorted_words = sort { sum values %{$totals{$a}} <=> sum values %{$totals{$b}} } keys %totals; #Probably something fancier here.

for my $word (@sorted_words[0, 1]) {
    #say {$totals_fh} $word, join('', keys %{$totals{$word}} ), "\t- ", function_to_decide_text($totals{$word});
    say {$totals_fh} $word, reduce {
            $totals{$word}{ substr $a, 0, 1 } == $totals{$word}{$b} ? $a . $b
          : $totals{$word}{ substr $a, 0, 1 } > $totals{$word}{$b} ? $a
          :                                                          $b;
    } keys %{ $totals{$word} };
}
```

EDIT: Forgot about the only two winners part. Fixed, somewhat.

EDIT2: Fixed as per comments.

Comment: You aren't storing the lines in a hash, just the count for each word and it's symbols; the data structure looks something like { are => { '$' => 10, '&' => 1 }, we => { '$' => 1, '#' => 11 } }; So chances are the hash will be nowhere near that big.

Comment: Well, just tested it, and it seems to runs just fine (generates the outfile with the two results and all) -- You'll have to define function_to_decide_text yourself, though.

Comment: If you didn't change the for my $word part, then the error should be in @sorted_words[0,1] - It's not getting filled. Try adding use Data::Dumper; say Dumper \@sorted_words; just before the for.

Comment: @aliocee, true enough. Just edited in a version that does what you want, although I'm positive that I did an awful job at it.

Comment: @aliocee: New requirements, uh. For this one to work, you'll need to change the regex to something like /(\p{Ll})\t(\p{Lu})/, and then change how the string concatenation in the reduce works. You'll have to figure that one out yourself, though.

Comment: If you don't say which error, then there's not much anyone can do.

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $word in hash element at maj.pl line 16, <$_[...]> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $sign in hash element at maj.pl line 16, <$_[...]> line 1. for all 10 lines.
Use of uninitialized value $word in hash element at maj.pl line 16, <$_[...]> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $sign in hash element at maj.pl line 16, <$_[...]> line 2.

Comment: Problem's in the regex. What are you using?

Comment: i have a question, what if the number of files increase from 5 to 10?

Comment: Change the map from 1..5 to 1..10; But for a better solution, if your files are all in the same directory, use File::Find::Rule; my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->name( qr!words[1-9][0-9]*\.txt$! )->in( directory_name_here ); If they aren't in the same directory, you could pass their paths as arguments to the script (then replace @files with @ARGV), or hardcode them.

Comment: how about the condition to determine the winner?

Comment: How did it change? I'd think you'd have to change the `$a . $b` to `$a . '|' . $b;` or `join('|', $a, $b);`. but that should be about it.

Comment: but now i have 10 files and 5 tags (from A,B,C,D to A,B,C,D,E) which means the decision have to change to determine the winner.

Comment: Why? It's still counting how many times any symbol appears, and still displaying the result(s) that show up the most.

Comment: /([a-z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)/; or /(\p{Ll})\t(\p{Lu})/; both are not working to match the word variable it give this error: Use of uninitialized value $word in hash element at maj.pl line 16, <$_[...]> line 1.

Comment: The second regex won't work because it's not meant to work: It's missing any qualifiers (+*?); at most, it'd match a lowercase letter, a tab, and an uppercase letter. You should seriously consider reading perlretut (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Dunno about the first though. Does it match your data in http://rubular.com/ or http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ ?

Comment: Then the data you posted earlier isn't in the same format as the one you are using. You'll have to toy around with the regex.

Comment: yes i told you i finished with the punctuation part, now im dealing with the letters part separated by tab(i.e. We   A, are   D, etc), yesterday i tried changing the question but Jonathan told me not to change because ur answers will be irrelevant.

Comment: I know. I've been telling you how to adapt this answer to those new requirements ever since. But you see, the data you posted then didn't have uppercase letters on the first part. See how that would affect all the regexes I've posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files   = qw(file1 file2 file3 file4 file5);
my $symbols = '*#$&'; # no need to escape them as they'll be in a character class
my %words;

foreach my $file (@files) {
   open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Cannot open $file: $!";
   while (<$fh>) {
      if (/^(\w+[$symbols])$/) {
         $words{$1} ++; # count the occurrences of each word
      }
   }
   close $fh;
}

my $counter  = 0;
my $previous = -1;

foreach my $word (sort {$words{$b} <=> $words{$a}} keys %words) {

   # make sure you don't exit if two words at the top of the list 
   # have the same number of occurrences
   if ($previous != $words{$word}) {
      last if $counter > 1;
   }
   $counter ++; # count the output
   $previous = $words{$word};

   print "$word occurred $words{$word} times.\n";
}
```

Worked when I tried it out...

Comment: Thanks, but i just want to create exactly the same file as the input files which contains only the winning words. but when i have 2 winners then i have to show both symbols. not count.

Comment: @aliocee Why not go with Hugmeir's answer then? It seems rather elegant! And in case it doesn't quite meet your needs - just modify it a bit...